# Mock method implementation using Google Mock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I'm mocking Arduino [`millis`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Millis) method using Google Mock. This method returns number of milliseconds since device starts. I would like to return increased number (in range 0 to Infinity) on every method call.

So far, I'm mocking this function like that:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*arduino, millis())
  .WillOnce(Return(0))
  .WillOnce(Return(1))
  .WillOnce(Return(2))
  // and so on...
```

But it's impractical. Is there a better way which works on infinite number of calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a custom action that will return incrementing numbers and use it in `WillRepeatedly`:

```
ACTION(ReturnIncreasingIntegers) {
    static int n = 0;
    return ++n;
}

EXPECT_CALL(*arduino, millis())
    .WillRepeatedly(ReturnIncreasingIntegers());
```

But I would advise against that. The less deterministic your test is, the harder it is to understand the behavior of the code under test there.